# Compute the integral $\int_{\delta_{B_1(-2)}} \frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}dz$

Tags: integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Could you please help me to solve this integral. I have no idea on how to proceed. Thank you.

I think, i should rewrite $\frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}$ as  a sum from a geometric series and then use the Cauchy integral formula, but I don´t see a trick..

$\int_{\delta_{B_1(-2)}} \frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}dz=\oint\frac{\frac{1}{z}}{(z+2)^3}dz$

Then

$\oint\frac{\frac{1}{z}}{(z+2)^3}dz=\left(\frac{2\pi i }{2!}\right)\left[\frac{d^2f(z)}{dz^2}\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\left(\frac{2\pi i }{2!}\right)\left[\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{1}{z})\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\left({\pi i}\right)\left[{\frac{2}{(z)^3}}\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\color{blue}{-\frac{1\pi i}{4}}$

Is that correct?

---

2. Solution (geometric progression)

$\int_{\delta_{B_1(-2)}} \frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}dz$

$\frac{1}{z(z+2)^3} = 2*(1-(1+\frac{z}{2}))^{-1}*\frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}$

$=\frac{2}{z(z+2)^3}*\frac{1}{1-(1+\frac{z}{2})}$

---

We know, that

$\frac{1}{1-(1+\frac{z}{2})}=\sum_{n=0}^∞ {(1+\frac{z}{2})^n}=1+(1+\frac{z}{2})^1+(1+\frac{z}{2})^2+(1+\frac{z}{2})^3+ ...)$

---

So we get

$\frac{2}{z(z+2)^3}*\frac{1}{1-(1+\frac{z}{2})}=\frac{2}{z(z+2)^3}*(1+(1+\frac{z}{2})^1+(1+\frac{z}{2})^2+(1+\frac{z}{2})^3+ ...)=$

$=\frac{4}{(z+2)^3}+\frac{z}{(z+2)^3}+\frac{1/2}{(z+2)}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2+z}{8}+...$

=>
$f(z)=1/2, z=-2
=>
2\pi if(z)=2\pi i*1/2=\pi i$

In this solution I have $\color{blue}{\pi i}$

And in the top solution I have another answer $\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}$.

What's my mistake?

Comment: If you really want to do it the way you suggest just write $\frac{1}{z}$ as $-2(1-\frac{z+2}{2})$, expand as a GP, and when you multiply by $\frac{1}{z+2}$ all is holomorphic apart from the $(z+2)$ term.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint, how to expend $\frac{(-2)(1-\frac{z+2}{2})}{(z+2^3)})$ as a geom. progression?

Comment: (I think I forgot an exponent $(-1)$.) It is constant times $ \frac{1}{\zeta^3}(1-\frac{\zeta}{2})^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The only enclosed pole is a third-order one at $z=-2$, so [the residue is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles) $\tfrac12\lim_{z\to-2}\tfrac{d^2}{dz^2}[(z-2)^3f(z)]$. I leave you to evaluate this, then multiply by $2i\pi$.

Comment: $\int_{\delta_{B_1(-2)}} \frac{1}{z(z+2)^3}dz=\oint\frac{\frac{1}{z}}{(z+2)^3}dz$

$\oint\frac{\frac{1}{z}}{(z+2)^3}dz=\left(\frac{2\pi i }{2!}\right)\left[\frac{d^2f(z)}{dz^2}\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\left(\frac{2\pi i }{2!}\right)\left[\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{1}{z})\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\left({\pi i}\right)\left[{\frac{2}{(z)^3}}\right]_{z=-2}$

$=\color{blue}{-\frac{1\pi i}{4}}$


Is that correct?

Comment: @Julia Well done! (You don't need the $\color{blue}{1}$factor, though.)